QGIS Geometry Generator Fails to Create Lines
I am trying to generate a hachure map using the QGIS tutorial How to create a tasty monochrome hachure map in QGIS.
The tutorial is straight forward but when I apply the geometry generator to my point data the data disappear.
The tutorial states to populate points along the contour lines with slope and aspect - which I did from a slope and aspect raster of my surface model.  Then you are to use the following geometry generator expression in the point data symbology.
Here is the geometry generator expression shown in the tutorial.
make_line( 
          $geometry, 
          project( 
                   $geometry, 
                   90 + 200 * “Slope” / 90, radians((“angle” - 90) + rand(0, 8)) 
          )
                  )

The attribute columns in my data differ than those in the tutorial but as you can see I have change the parameters accordingly in my geometry generator expression shown here.

 make_line( 
              $geometry, 
              project( 
                       $geometry, 
                       90 + 200 * “slope1” / 90, radians((“aspect1” - 90) + rand(0, 8)) 
           )
                      )

It looks like my symbology settings are the same as shown in the tutorial.

I am new to geometry generators in QGIS but the expression looks good considering the explanation in the tutorial.
Why do my geometry generator based symbologies fail to display?

Are these normal double quotes (ASCII HEX 022 ") that enclose the field name? These look like other quotation marks.

@Kasluk24 -  That was it, they must have copied differently from the webpage.  If you post that as an answer I will mark it correct.

@CBG: To help you debug future issues, see this picture for how to get some explanations as to why an expression doesn't work.

To conclude this topic, the solution also as an answer:
The expression was copied from a website where typographic quotes were used.
The field name must be enclosed in normal double quotes ASCII HEX 022 "

Or use the field name without any quotation marks, this also works
